# Deezer API - Erro de requisição JSON com $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api

Ao tentar realizar uma busca simples no **Deezer API** (API de busca Pública sem Necessidade de Chave de Autenticação) eu recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro como retorno:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.deezer.com/search?q=Bang. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

O Código utilizado para realizar a busca:

```
$.getJSON(
    "http://api.deezer.com/search?q=Bang",
    function(dados) {
        console.log(dados);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar chamadas entre domínios é necessário usar o JSONP, e para que o servidor saiba que espera um JSONP como retorno é necessário adicionar o parâmetro `output=jsonp`.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: "http://api.deezer.com/search?q=Bang&output=jsonp",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonCallback",
    cache:false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        // função antes de executar a chamada
    },
    success: function(data,statusText,xhr) {
        // função quando ocorrer sucesso
    }
});

function jsonCallback (data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muito útil @marcusagm